# Selenium WebDrivers -Not able to select dynamic check box which has no name

Tags: selenium

```
<div id="checkboxfield-3844" class="x-field x-form-item x-field-default x-form-cb-checked x-form-dirty" style="width: 492px;">
    <label id="checkboxfield-3844-labelEl" class="x-form-item-label x-form-item-label-left" style="margin-right:5px;width:200px;" for="ext-gen6460">Is Stitching Point:</label>
    <div id="checkboxfield-3844-bodyEl" class="x-form-item-body x-form-cb-wrap" role="presentation" style="width: 287px;">
        <input id="ext-gen6460" class="x-form-field x-form-checkbox" type="button" hidefocus="true" autocomplete="off" aria-checked="true" aria-invalid="false" role="checkbox" aria-describedby="checkboxfield-3844-errorEl" style="-moz-user-select: text;" data-errorqtip="">
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxfield-3844-errorEl" class="x-form-error-msg" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="x-clear" role="presentation"></div>
</div>
```

This is my Div , out of it iam not able to select the checkbox since there is no name .Need some help on this

Comment: Please provide some details, and share some part of your code which causes the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming there is only one 'label tag' with innerHTML/text as "Is Stiching Point:", the below xpath will point to the checkbox:-**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[.='Is Stitching Point:']/..//input[@role='checkbox']")).click();
```

**NOTE:** Above is a java code. In case you are using a different language binding, you can refer this to employ the same thing.

### Edit

Below is the alternative way using **JavascriptExecutor**:

```
WebElement element  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[.='Is Stitching Point:']/..//input[@role='checkbox']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: any other way is there ?

Comment: @Arunkumar : I have added an alternative using the **JavascriptExecutor**. See if that works for you. Else, can you please provide the HTML code snippet of the grid please ?

Comment: if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[.='Is Stitching Point:']/..//input[@role='checkbox']")).isEnabled() )
 {
  System.out.println("Enabled");
  if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[.='Is Stitching Point:']/..//input[@role='checkbox']")).isDisplayed() )
  {
   System.out.println("Displayed");  
  }
  if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[.='Is Stitching Point:']/..//input[@role='checkbox']")).isSelected())
  {
   System.out.println("Selected");
  } Returns nothing for these checks

Comment: @Arunkumar: Is the grid inside any frame or something ? Like, if you use the **Firepath** of **Firebug** and inspect the checkbox, does it show **iframe** on the top left of the **Firebug** as shown in this image: [http://i.imgur.com/avW2b7H.png](http://i.imgur.com/avW2b7H.png)

Comment: UI is developed using Ext-js. in browser it is rendered as html

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't able to help you. Tried all possible way, I knew of. If only, it was a public site, or you had something similar, I would've persevered to help you find one solution. :|

Comment: thats okay, thanks a lot for your help :-) u r great

Comment: I understood the problem now ... the same code is there in 3 ways without any changes ..so it picks 3 of them when i run in my console...i have trie this way also but it still picks 3 of them

Comment: xpath ->"//label[text()='Is Stitching Point:']/following-sibling::div[1]"

Comment: Any suggestion on this

Comment: Okay then change your xpath to `//label[text()='Is Stitching Point:'][1]/following-sibling::div[1]` to detect the first element, `//label[text()='Is Stitching Point:'][2]/following-sibling::div[1]` to detect the second element, and `//label[text()='Is Stitching Point:']/following-sibling::div[1]` to get the third element. Or, else use **`driver.findElements("//label[text()='Is Stitching Point:']/following-sibling::div[1]")`** and get all the elements of this type (assign them to a List of course), and then traverse through the list and click whichever element you desire.